# Dynamic Loading Dex IncompatibleClassChangeError: Structural change of

Tags: android, dex

I have a question about dynamic loading of dex. When debugging is running, it can run successfully, but when I officially package it, there will be a

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Structural change of androidx.appcompat.widget. AppCompatImageView is hazardous (/data/user/0/package/appddex/dynamic. dex at compile time,/data/app/package/at/x86/base. odex at runtime): Direct method count off: 3 vs. 2.

How do I need to solve this problem? Thanks

When dynamically loading dex, this issue will occur before versions earlier than Android 10, and will not occur above that version.

Comment: Is the dex file you try to load is a dex file or an odex file (I mean from the file structure not the file.extension)? odex files are more or less device dependent, so you should not include it in an APK. Based on the error message I would assume your file is an odex file.

Comment: I am loading a dex file that was converted from an app (meaning I am loading a dex file). The loading process was successful, but when I try to navigate to the Activity in the dex file, I receive an error message with the aforementioned error.